# Trouble Using Input and Arraylists

Tags: java

I am having trouble. I am trying to allow a user to input a parameter for a method in another file. However it is giving me two errors. Can anyone help me please

```
public int countItem(Item purchase)
     {
        int quantity = 0;
        if(cart.indexOf(purchase) == -1)
            quantity = 0;
        else
             quantity = purchase.getQuantity() ;

        return quantity;
             }
```

This is from my second file.

```
 System.out.println ("What item do you want to find?");
                purchase = input.nextline(); //ERROR ERROR
                System.out.println("You have " + basket.countItem() + purchase + "soup in your cart."); // ERROR
```

These are the errors am I getting.

```
 --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
F:\School\CS I AP\Chapter 7\Shopping Cart Lab\Shop.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
            purchase = input.nextline();
            ^
  symbol:   variable purchase
  location: class Shop
F:\School\CS I AP\Chapter 7\Shopping Cart Lab\Shop.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
            purchase = input.nextline();
```

I also realized I got a third error.

```
error: method countItem in class ShoppingCart cannot be applied to given types;
```

Comment: is purchase declared in the second file?

Comment: I like the name of the folder on your flash drive

Comment: More context is probably needed.  What is input?  The simplest thing might be: is "purchase" defined in the second file somewhere?  If not, you want to say:  Item purchase = input.nextline();

Comment: for third error, countItem method is returning int value. If you are assigning returned value to a variable make sure it is of compatible type.

Comment: @Reddy He calls `countItem()` without parameter, while it is declared with one parameter of type `Item`: `public int countItem(Item purchase)`. That's why he gets the third error.

Comment: @MockerTim, yes you are right. I was in too much hurry.

Comment: @Reddy Don't hurry, be happy! :)

Comment: Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Java compiler cannot find the variable `purchase`. There are a few scenarios for this:

1. The `Item` class is in another folder and has not been imported. (very common error)
2. The variable `purchase` has not been declared.
3. Typo errors in the variable name, variable declaration, or method name.

From your error, it seems that you have not declared the variable `purchase`. It should be:
`String purchase = input.nextLine();`

Also, you made a typo. It should be `nextLine()` instead of `nextline()`.

Bear in mind that you need to convert your `purchase` object from a `String` into an `Item` object, since your `countItem()` method only accepts an `Item` object. The `nextLine()` method from the `Scanner` class only returns a `String` object, you cannot force it directly into a `Item` object or you will get another compiler error. **For example**, if you had a constructor for a new `Item` object that takes in a `String`:

```
Item item = new Item(purchase); 
int count = itemCount(item);
```

As for your third error, you had declared your `countItem()` method to take in one parameter of type `Item`, but in your code you are calling it without any parameters, hence the compiler complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare purchase.

`String purchase`

Comment: You should be more attentive! It's `purchase`, not purcash.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because the program doesn't know what the variable `purchase` is.  Basically, there is not an object by the name of `purchase` in scope at the time that it is being called.

If you could post some more of the code to show the full scope of your Main method, that would help us show you where to define `purchase` so that it is in scope when it is called.

the last error is fixed with `()`, ie:

```
 System.out.println("You have " + (basket.countItem() + purchase) + "soup in your cart.");
```

or like this:

```
 int temp = basket.countItem() + purchase;
 System.out.println("You have " + temp + "soup in your cart.");
```

That is of course, assuming that purchase is an `int`. More context is needed to be sure